# Reading a folder with multiple excel files which contain more than 15 sheets each into a loop to be processed for feature extraction

Tags: python, excel, pandas, loops, batch-processing

community. I hope you can offer some guidance as I am new to python programming

I am trying to read a folder that contains 15 excel files and each excel file has 30 worksheets. I am trying to read each excel worksheet separately because I need to extract the features from the 30 sheets. I need to read the excel sheets using a pandas data frame, however, when I try to do it appears empty. I am not sure how to proceed from here, I have tried to place just df into the df_frame but I get an error.
[image: This is the error]
[image: This is what I get when I try to print the data frame, it is empty!]

[image: This is essentially what I get when I print everything, you can see it prints the 15 excel sheets and the 30 worksheets but the pandas data frame are empty]

Get the current working directory
print("The current working directory is:")

print(os.getcwd())

## folder path

path = r'C:\Users'
excel_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.xlsx"))

## loop over the list of excel files

for files in excel_files:

```
# read the csv file
df = pd.read_excel(files,sheet_name=None)
df_frame = pd.DataFrame(df,columns= ['Time','Sensor'])  


# print the location and filename
print (df_frame)
display(df_frame)
#print('Location:', files)
#print('File Name:', files.split("\\")[-1])
  
# print the content
#print('Content:')
#display(df)
```

## print()`

I have tried to work around the message error, however, I don't know how to make the df_frame = pd.DataFrame(df,columns= ['Time','Sensor']) to be applied to all the excel worksheet in all the excel files.

P.s I don't need to join the excel worksheets into 1 single sheet at the moment. I just want to be able to read separately to be able to proceed with the feature extraction and then join the extracted features together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `df = pd.read_excel(files,sheet_name=None)` creates a dictionary, with the dictionary keys being the string name of each sheet and the dictionary values being the data found in each sheet in a pandas data frame.

You can loop through like so:

```
df_dict = pd.read_excel(files,sheet_name=None)
for sheet_name, df in df_dict.items():
    ## Rest of code here
```